# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near - at line 1

Tags: mysql, localhost

I have this issue here with my code, and cant find where the problem actually is, has anyone had similar issue?

```
<?php
include("db.php"); 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=$_POST['namename'];
$job=$_POST['job'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$insert=mysql_query("insert into     commenttable(name,job,message)values('$name','$job','$message')")or     die(mysql_error());
header("Location:../home.php");
}
?>
```

this is running on localhost

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.42 - Source distribution

forgot to mention that if I post simple comment such a "Hello" it works fine, but when i try to post comment like this

```
<INPUT TYPE="IMAGE" SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">
```

for a attack it wont work and I get the error message.
Im doing this for small attack project, this is why i need to get this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be $name, $job, and/or $message have a `'` in them. You should be using parameterized queries; or at least trying sanitize input.

Comment: To help find the source of this kind of issues it's often helpful to first store the query string in a variable, and `echo` that variable. Also, you're using the deprecated mysql_ functions, you should really switch to mysqli_ or pdo.

Comment: so how my code should look like? As im not very experienced in php programming. 
And this is small project, which wont make any difference what sql I'll be using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code fails when you are trying to insert the text `<INPUT TYPE="IMAGE" SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">` then obviously, what is happening is what Uueerdo suggested in his comment: the single quote right before "XSS" is interpreted by MySQL as the closing single quote of the string, leaving you with a dangling `XSS');'`, which is, of course, a syntax error.

There are two ways to overcome this problem:

1. Programmatically escape the single quotes.  This would be quite tricky if you were to do it by yourself, but there ought to be some library function in PHP for that, so it would look like `message = escape_for_sql( message )`. (Sorry I am not reproducing the dollar signs, I am allergic.)
2. Better yet, use a parameterized query, where you construct your query using a "?" in place of each value, signifying a parameter to the query, then you supply the value for each parameter, and *then* you execute the query. I don't know how this is done in PHP, search for "parameterized query PHP".

Comment: please see my edited post, and thanks for your reply!

Comment: @GediminasTam Oh, I see. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Mike's answer, the correct prepared-statement PHP syntax would be, using the **mysql** driver:

```
None. Don't use the mysql driver. It's been deprecated since forever.
```

Using **mysqli:**

```
// You need to define the following $db_* vars elsewhere
$dbh = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name;)

$query = "INSERT INTO commenttable (name, job, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($name, $job, $message);
$stmt->execute();

// When you're finished...
$stmt->close();
```

Using **PDO:**

```
// Edit the connection string as appropriate for your installation
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mydbhost;dbname=whatever', $db_user, $db_password);

$query = "INSERT INTO commenttable (name, job, message) VALUES (:name, :job, :message)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$params = array(':name' => $name, ':job' => $job, ':message' => $message);
$stmt->execute($params);

// PDO has no explicit close() call.
```

I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you from me, and also on behalf of the OP.  The original intent of stackoverflow was to edit people's answers if you have an amendment to make, but this is rarely followed, and it is unlikely that it ever will, because by posting your own separate answer you can receive upvotes, like the one I just gave you.  C-:=

Comment: Thanks. I didn't edit your answer because I though  it would be rude of me.